# Dynamically loaded html doesnt have access to viewModel

Tags: aurelia

I will give a simple case scenario to illustrate my problem. I have a view and a viewModel. The viewModel has a method redirect(). After my view and its model are loaded I dynamically add a html button to the page and use click.delegate to link to method redirect() in viewModel. But clicking the button doesn't call the method. How to fix this. 
If binding is not a possible workaround

Comment: how are you "dynamically adding a html" ? could you show an example?

Comment: In my app, there is a table. Each row displays customer data. Last item contains some buttons that u can use to do things like view/edit/delete a customer. The table is created dynamically. I cant create a custom element or attribute. It must be made dynamically. So the issue is I cant make the buttons call any methods as stated by the answer below. Is there a workarond?

Comment: Oh and by dynamically I mean in the attached callback I make a fetch call, get some data and create a table using a plugin

Comment: please add some code to your question

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add new bindings to the DOM through DOM manipulation because they will not be bound properly.

Instead you should either conditionally show it -

```
<button click.delegate="redirect()" if.bind="showRedirect">Redirect</button>
```